# Cannot Install Ubuntu over win7

Tags: boot

I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04 as a secondary OS over Win7. I made my USB flash drive bootable by using 'unetbootin-windows-608' tool. Then, I created a new 25GB-partition on the disk. After restarting and booting from flash drive, I installed Ubuntu on that partition. At the end of installation, I restarted my laptop. However, there is no Ubuntu as a new OS. Still, win7 is opening. Then, I noticed that the new partition has gone also. What is the reason and solution?

Comment: Did you install windows and Ubuntu on the same HDD?

Comment: Yes, I created a new partition on the disk. Then, I tried to install ubuntu on that partition.

Comment: reboot and press shift durin boot time this would take you to the Grub menu so you can choose the Ubuntu

Comment: I will perform some significant operations. Thus, I should have a settled and permanent Ubuntu, not temporary. Actually, PC should ask me to choose one of the installed OS in it.

Comment: What happened to the partition? Did u see the partition from Windows? Is it showing free space? or has linux parition? You can boot from live ubuntu cd/usb and see the what happened to the installation. If you see the installation in the partition, then you can try reinstalling grub, it might solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a boot-able flash drive using "Universal USB Installer",

use  downloaded version of the ubuntu desktop .iso file either the 32- or 64-bit.

Comment: I tried that way. However, it didn't work also.

Comment: which option is selected in installation type?  can you selected replace windows 7 with Ubuntu in installation type option? that will delete your all windows program and windows will be replaced by Ubuntu. make sure downloaded .iso file is not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

[This question is somewhat old, but answers such as these help many other people, besides the original poster, who stumble into the topic.]

The installation finished without errors, so I will assume Ubuntu installed correctly.

The 25 GB partition was no longer visible under windows because it is formatted to ext, which Windows can't read. No problem here.

The grub menu at boot to choose which OS to load did not appear. This could mean that something is not right with grub. to fix this boot Ubuntu in live mode (with your live usb) and in the terminal install boot repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
then use it to fix grub.